# Oracle OC4J (aka Orion) parameter -userThreads

Tags: oc4j

Anyone know what this parameter does, it is used in starting up Oracle's oc4j application server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in a Java EE application server like that you "should" be using EJB and let the EJB container handle the threading.
If you do use thread, they won't be able to access the Application server resources (the context) such as data sources and other JNDI resources. 
In order to be able to do context lookups from user created threads  you should use that parameter.